# How should I change it to remove the last element from this list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to remove the last element from an arraylist but pop() method here is not working as I wanted. How should I change the code?

```
public String pop(){
    String last;
    if (stringList.size() == 0){
        return null;    

    } else {
        last = stringList.get(stringList.size()-1);
        return last;
        stringList.remove(stringList.size() - 1); //This is giving me error!
           }
}
```

Comment: The compiler will never reach the code after return.

Answer (score 4):

```
return stringList.remove(stringList.size() - 1);
```

The rest can be removed, as `remove` returns the removed item.

Answer (score 1):

code behind a `return` statement can never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Return statement should be at last because compiler assumes that there is nothing after return statement and it may say *unreachable statement*

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing `return last;` statement before `stringList.remove(stringList.size() - 1);` and any statement after return statement never executed.

Modified code:

```
else {
    last = stringList.get(stringList.size()-1);
    stringList.remove(stringList.size() - 1); //Now it wont give any error!
    return last;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any statement after a `return` statement won't be accessible(*unreachable code error*). `return` statements should generally be the last statement you wish to execute in a method().

Bubble up the statement giving the error above the `return` and the code should work just fine.

```
stringList.remove(stringList.size() - 1); //goes above the return
return last;
```

Answer (score 0):

### `List#getLast` & `List#removeLast`

In Java 21+, `List` is a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html). See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

So now `List` offers convenient methods such as [`getLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getLast()) and [`removeLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeLast()).

```
String lastString = myStringList.getLast() ;
myStringList.removeLast() ;
```